# filtering data while pulling it from bigquery storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the code as below to load google blob storage(bucket) metadata to bigquery. The code is not completing because I am not able to apply any filter on the blobs. In fact the blobs do have "updated" field. Any help to to filter the blob data for current day is appreciated. Also, if you have any other filter suggestions that will be helpful. Thanks.

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = Clients.get_client(ClientType.STORAGE)
client1 = Clients.get_client(ClientType.BIGQUERY)

def list_blobs_with_prefix(prefixes):
    data_list = []
    for Index, row in df2.iterrows():
        buckets = client.list_buckets(project=row['project'],prefix=prefixes)
        for bucket in buckets:
            blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket.name, delimiter=None,prefix=prefixes)
            for blob in blobs:
                df_list = [blob.name, blob.bucket.name, blob.storage_class, blob.id, blob.size, str(blob.updated),
                           blob.generation, blob.metageneration, blob.etag, str(blob.owner), str(blob.component_count),
                           str(blob.cache_control), blob.content_type, str(blob.content_disposition),
                           str(blob.content_encoding), str(blob.content_language)]
                if len(df_list) > 0:
                     data_list.append(df_list)
        #
            if len(data_list) > 0:
                    df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns = ['name','bucket_name','storage_class','id','size','updated','generation','metageneration','etag','owner','component_count','cache_control','content_type','content_disposition','content_encoding','content_language'])
                    df['project'] = row['project']
                    df = df.astype('str')
                    data_list = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prefixes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's' ,'t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    list_blobs_with_prefix(prefixes)
```

Comment: What is the error when the script is ran? Is it expected that you use the same prefixes for both buckets and blobs? This would mean that your buckets have the same name with your blobs. Can you show a sample folder structure on your bucket? Just so this could be reproduced by the community. Also just to confirm, is your goal is to get the blobs when `updated` is equal to the date today (ex. `updated` = 2022-01-10, today = 2022-01-10 then put these in a data frame)?

Comment: There is no error when the code ran. But the job is not completing even after 12 hours. The aim is to get the blob metadata for the current day for hundreds of projects everyday. The general structure of the storage is as follows.           
    Name ,created,Location type,Location, last modified, storage class etc.

Comment: And to add more context I am adding prefixes only as a mechanism to filter the results. We don't necessarily have the bucket name same as blobs.

Comment: Please post your actual code.  This example doesn't run.  Flake8 lists four `undefined name` errors and two `overidented` errors along with a stack of warnings.

Comment: How do we know that performance is poor? If there are hundreds of projects in `df2` each with hundreds of buckets each with a million blobs then this is going to run for hours.  How many projects, buckets, and blobs are there?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code you can add a simple filtering logic at the part where you created the dataframe. Where you can converted column `updated` to datetime and format it to **YYYY-MM-DD** so you can compare it with a date value filter the dataframe. See the code below:

```
if len(data_list) > 0:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns = ['name','bucket_name','storage_class','id','size','updated','generation','metageneration','etag','owner','component_count','cache_control','content_type','content_disposition','content_encoding','content_language'])
    df['updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['updated'])
    df['updated'] = df['updated'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    filtered = df[df['updated']=='2021-05-31'] # change '2021-05-31' to something like datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') to get the date today
    print(filtered)
```

NOTE: I'm not sure if this will perform well on your buckets since we don't know the number of buckets and files you have.

Comment: I am exactly doing this . But it will be more helpful if we can add a filter to the source. It seems adding filter to the source is currently not supported. Thanks.